# Format Table in JIRA

Tags: jira

I am trying to pass a string into JIRA via an API call and have the string formatted like I have below. String ->

```
"This is a message with a table. \\\ ||A||B||C|| \\\ |1|2|3|  \\\ |4|5|6|"
```

Expected Output:

```
This is a message with a table
| A | B | C |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

Pretty much what is in the URL below but my line breakers in the message aren't working. Any help is appreciated.

https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables

Answer (score 1):

Try `\n` or even `\r\n` in your submitted string instead of the `\\`.  I've used `\\` when I want to start a new line in JIRA's *output*, but I think you need the line break on the *input* here.